# Visual Studio 2010 projects cannot be loaded

Tags: visual-studio-2010, load, project

I have successfully converted a visual studio solution with two projects (class library, web application) from 2008 to 2010. I can open the solution with projects in one environment (windows 8) without projects.
On another system (Windows Server 2008 R2) with visual studio 2010, the projects are not loaded. A reload fails; files are displayed shortly and than again marked as unavailable.
I have no idea why this happens. Could it be a missing patch for visual studio? Right now, I have the following installation:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Shell cannot load these types of projects.